DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE ORA-29491: invalid table for chunking
I am trying to recreate the process "CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID"
https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2#create_a_task
but failed.
I follow the following steps:
 CONN / AS SYSDBA
 GRANT CREATE JOB TO test;  
  /        
 CONN test/test
  /
  DROP TABLE test_tab;
  /
  CREATE TABLE test_tab (
   id          NUMBER,
   description VARCHAR2(50),
   num_col     NUMBER,
   session_id  NUMBER,
   CONSTRAINT test_tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
      );
      /
  INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO test_tab
   SELECT level,
   'Description for ' || level,
    CASE
    WHEN MOD(level, 5) = 0 THEN 10
    WHEN MOD(level, 3) = 0 THEN 20
        ELSE 30
          END,
         NULL
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 500000;
    COMMIT;
      /
    EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(USER, 'TEST_TAB', cascade => TRUE);
     /
     BEGIN
      DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task (task_name => 'test_task');
     END;

When doing this step
    BEGIN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chunks_by_rowid(task_name   => 'test_task',
                                               table_owner => 'TEST',
                                               table_name  => 'TEST_TAB',
                                               by_row      => TRUE,
                                               chunk_size  => 10000);
    END;

i get the following errors:
ORA-29491: invalid table for chunking
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE", line 28
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE", line 14
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE", line 126
ORA-06512: at line 2
29491. 00000 -  "invalid table for chunking"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to chunk a table by ROWID, but the table was not a physical table or the table was an IOT.
physical table or the table is an IOT.
*Action:   Use a table which has physical ROWID.

Do a select owner, table_name from   dba_tables where  table_name = 'TEST_TAB'; and make sure the table really exists and is owned by TEST.  According to your script, that should be the case, but the error you are getting suggests maybe it is not the case.  So, check just to make sure you're not crazy.

Related to @MatthewMcPeak, what happens if you make the table owner passed to gather_table_stats the same as that passed to create_chunks_by_rowid?  In other words, either make both user or both should be TEST and see if the problem disappears (or moves to gather_table_stats) which will indicate that you're logged in to the wrong schema or the table isn't where you expect it to be.
